# Messenger Send API File Attachment MP3 Unexpected internal error

Tags: json, facebook, audio, messenger

I'm trying to send an audio file that can be downloaded via the Send API from Facebook Messenger. The process works fine for an audio attachment, but then the user cannot download the audio file, they can only play it in messenger. However, when sending it as a file attachment it throws an Unexpected internal error. The resulting error code/subcode are not listed in the Facebook API docs. Any ideas?

JSON for audio attachment:

```
{
    recipient: {
        id: recipientId
    },
    message: {
        attachment: {
            type: "audio",
            payload: {
                url: URL_FOR_AUDIO
            }
        }
    }
}
```

JSON for file attachment:

```
{
    recipient: {
        id: recipientId
    },
    message: {
        attachment: {
            type: "file",
            payload: {
                url: URL_FOR_AUDIO
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Resulting error message:

```
{ error:
    { message: '(#-1) Unexpected internal error',
      type: 'OAuthException',
      code: -1,
      error_subcode: 2018012,
      fbtrace_id: 'Fuc2YJu096W' } } }
```